# I want to make node views "Edit link" field as a menu

Tags: views, 6, routes

Is it possible to make "Edit link" field as a menu.
On my site one user can create only node and I have a page view which displays the node the user logged on has created.
This views has a "Edit link" field so that the user can jump to node edit page from this view page.

However I want to have a menu or tab that can directly link to the node edit page of the node the logged in user has created.
It should a menu or a tab that says "edit my node" and the user can directly jump to the node edit page without visiting the page views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu items in Drupal are cached, so you cannot make them dynamic. I recommend that you do like the user module in Drupal core does for the /user path.

First, create a custom module. In your custom module, implement [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) like this:

```
$items['my-page'] = array(
  'title' => 'My page', 
  'page callback' => 'edit_my_page', 
  'access callback' => TRUE, 
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
);
```

This will link the url example.com/my-page to the view_my_page() function. The view_my_page function could look like this (similar to [user_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.pages.inc/function/user_page/6)):

```
function edit_my_page() {
  global $user;
  $my_nid = 0;

  // Write your own code here to retrieve the Node ID for the
  // current user and store the Node ID in $my_nid.

  if ($my_nid) {
    menu_set_active_item('node/' . $my_nid . '/edit');
    return menu_execute_active_handler();
  }
  else {
    return drupal_get_form('user_login');
  }
}
```

Now, when a user navigates to example.com/my-page, Drupal will serve the correct node edit page.

Comment: Thank you very much.This looks very helpful but unfortunately This seems to be a bit over my head as I'm not really a coder. I was wishing to implement this function with an easier way..

Comment: In that case, I need to ask you: the content type of which users can only create one node, is it some kind of user profile? Because in that case, you could consider switching to the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module. It allows a one-node-per-user setup like you describe, and integrates with the user account page to make the profile easy to find and edit.

Comment: Yes,You have a very good guess. The node is for user profile. Thanks for your input.It looks like Content Profile is the ideal solution. I should have considered it before started building my site. Now I'll start looking up if I can shift the whole structure of my site. Thanks again it was really helpful.

Comment: If I remember correctly, content profile allows you to mark an existing content type as profile node. Good luck building your site!

Comment: Thanks. I could successfully convert my node type to profile content type and now working as I wanted :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working for you. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, because your question sounds like a basic Drupal feature that has been around for years: tabs with "local tasks" as they are called. Here is a screenshot from a Drupal 7 site, without any extra modules:

[image: a simple node in a default Drupal 7 installation]

If I understand correctly, the 'Edit' tab is what you are looking for... Or isn't that what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looks like my explanation didn't really describe what I need. I'm using [node limit number](http://drupal.org/project/node_limitnumber) module so that only one node can be created per user. And then I would like to have a menu item  linked to the edit page of only the "node created by the currently logged-in  user"  which means I probably need a dynamic URL something like node/%/edit.  Or if the default drupal tab can do this I would like to have the tab on the user page like user/%/ Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm on Drupal6